# Setting up Tomcat JDBC connection pool with the Spring JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to setup a Tomcat connection pool (to MySQL) in my Java web app, while using the Spring JDBCTemplate.

This is the Java class to create the connection pool:

```
@Configuration
public class DataAccessConfiguration {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public javax.sql.DataSource datasource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:java-config");
        ds.setUsername("sa");
        ds.setPassword("");
        ds.setInitialSize(5);
        ds.setMaxActive(10);
        ds.setMaxIdle(5);
        ds.setMinIdle(2);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean public JdbcOperations tpl() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(datasource());
    }

}
```

This is how I get the `ApplicationContext` (in the main method for example):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
```

How should I define the `DataAccessConfiguration` class in the `Beans.xml` file so Spring knows to use it?

**

### Update:

**

This is the actual configuration method:

```
public javax.sql.DataSource datasource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUsername("root");
        p.setPassword("");
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(10);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors(
                "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
                "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        ds.setPoolProperties(p);
        return ds;
    }
```

Can you please help rewrite in the `Beans.xml`?

Comment: The name by default would be `dataSource`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza should I provide a class as well? If so, which class should it be? DataAccessConfiguration?

Comment: What is in your `Beans.xml` if there is component-scanning make sure the `@Configuration` class is picked up, else just add it as a bean to your xml file.

Comment: @M.Deinum - this is my question - how should I add it to my xml file? what is the format?

Comment: Just as any other bean... Why would it be different.

Comment: Use  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataAccessConfiguration.class) instead of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml") in your main method.

Comment: @M.Deinum - the class attribute of this `bean` should be the name of the class in my project? because all of the configuration is in the class itself, correct?

Comment: Or if you really, really want/ need to keep the new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml") then put <bean class="..DataAccessConfiguration"/> into your Beans.xml. This is however useless if you do not have other XML based beans.

Comment: @Michal - I do have other XML based beans so it's not useless. Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: I personally would try not to mix different configuration styles,  this is usually possible and not that difficult. But if you want/have to, then simply registering the configuration as bean shall do it.

Comment: You might also consider (depending on the ordering) http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext- using the  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataAccessConfiguration.class) as the parent parameter.

Comment: @Michal - if I use this how would I load the rest of the beans? I have a lot of DAO implemented classes that I need to use

Comment: Using the application context constructor with parent parameter/s allows to combine several application contexts together, just as <import resource="..."> does for XML based configuration or the @Import for annotation based configuration. In your case you probably would have parent = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataAccessConfiguration.class) and then ApplicationContext context = 
             new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml", parent); , where in Beans.xml you would have your DAO beans definitions. Sorry, I linked the one-parameter constructor in my previous comment.

Comment: I personally would however port the discussed @Configuration into XML in order to have one configuration style, with two beans it is not much effort.

Comment: Sorry one more hint - for web application might the approach with constructor with parent context happen to be not very well suited, at least if you would like to boot the context using one of the existing spring ContextLoaderListener. I do not think constructors with parameters might be used there.

Comment: @Michal - I have added the actual configuration in my app. Can you please show how to rewrite in the Beans.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the values passed in Properties setter methods exist. Therefore XML-based bean definition goes like:

```
<bean  name="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  ....
</bean>

<bean name="tpl" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence - can't I use all of the properties in the first bean?

Comment: You can set-up all properties of the bean the way I wrote. With the last sentence I was trying to indicate that the XML-based definition leads to slightly different Java execution path as when compared to your PoolProperties-based Java code. But now I have also seen that my last sentence was not not correct and deleted it.

Comment: Why is it executed differently? Is there a list of all of the properties that can be used in the bean definition? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The XML definition leads to Java code equivalent of org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(); ds.setUrl(...); ds.setDriverClassName(...); Your original code used the PoolProperties in between. But the difference does not matter at all. It would be posssible to set-up the XML with PoolProperties too but not the way I linked.

Comment: The properties of bean definition are Java Beans Properties. Anything you find in JavaDoc of the given bean class - here for example DataSource or JdbcTemplate - as having a setXxxx and getXxx method (said in simplified way) - is potentially a property usable in <property> tag.

Comment: last question - where can I get the JavaDoc for the DataSource bean class? I searched for it and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67531/discussion-between-david-tzoor-and-michal).

Answer (score -1):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="#{config['db.url']}" />
    <property name="driverClass" value="#{config['db.driver']}" />
    <property name="user" value="#{config['db.username']}" />
    <property name="password" value="#{config['db.password']}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```